# Typescript generic extends generic?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to build a map function in TS ([TS playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20%24TupleMap%3CT%20extends%20any%5B%5D%2C%20F%3E%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20F%3CT%5BP%5D%3E%0A%7D)):

```
type $TupleMap<T extends any[], F> = {
  [P in keyof T]: F<T[P]>
}
```

This yells at me saying `Type 'F' is not generic` on the `F<T[P]>` bit.

How do I define `F` to be a generic with one type argument?

Comment: You [can't](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213), sorry.  ☹

Comment: Workarounds may be forthcoming if you can post more about your specific use case

Comment: @jcalz - was afraid of that, but thanks!  This pretty much is my current use case.  I want a mapping function in TS, e.g. `Map<ary, unpack>`, `Map<ary, nullable>`, etc.  `UnpackArray`, etc is possible but I was just wondering if it'd be possible to make them less noisy.

Answer (score 0):

The key here is How to map a type a type to another.

The simplest is to use a function type like this one:

```
    type TestMapper = 
        ((p: boolean) => string) |
        ((p: string) => number);
```

Here is the way to "apply" the function type and get tha mapped type:

```
    type $Apply<F extends (p: any) => any, P extends Parameters<F>[0]>=
        F extends ((p: P) => infer R) ? R : never;
```

How to use this :

```
    type TFApplyedToString = $Apply<TestMapper, string>; // number
    type TFApplyedToBoolean = $Apply<TestMapper, boolean>; // string
```

Now we have to map the tuple :

```
    type $Map<T, F extends (p: any) => any> = {
        [P in keyof T]: $Apply<F, T[P]>;
    }
```

And finally :

```
    type TFApplyedToTuple = $TupleMap<[string, boolean, string], TestMapper>;
    // [number, string, number]
```

as a bonus you could map Objects Too :

```
    type TFApplyedToObject = $Map<{
        a: string,
        b: boolean,
        c: string
    }, TestMapper>;
    /*
    {
        a: number,
        b: string,
        c: number
    }
    */
```